# How to use tabulator list editor together with html formatter?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have options defined by id, label, description, e.g.

| id | label | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | foo_description |
| 2 | baa | baa_description |

And would like to use them in a tabulator column.

- The label should be used for display
- The description should be shown as hover title of the label.
- The id should be used when getting data from the table with getData()

I tried to use a [list editor](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/edit#editor-list) in combination with a [html cell formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/format#formatter-html) for a column.
It kind of works. If I hover over a cell in the table, I can see a hover title. And hover titles
are shown for the options in the list/select editor, too.

However, when opening the list editor, the **currently selected value is not shown as html** `foo` any more but as text `<span title=...>foo`.

After closing the editor, the cell is shown correctly again.

=> How can I format the currently selected value of the list editor?

=> Or how should I otherwise define a tabular column to fulfills my needs?

[image]

I also tried to use an item formatter for the list editor to show html titles. That works inside the list editor but the table cell does not show a tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it with a combination of

- custom cell formatter for the table
- custom item formatter for the list editor
- custom object class used for the values
- converting columns that include custom value objects to ids before returning the data

  ```
   class SelectableValue {

       constructor(id, label, description){
           this._id = id;
           this._label = label;
           this._description = description;
       }

       toString(){
           return '<span title="'+ this._description +'">' + this._label + '<span>';
       }

       get id(){
           return this.id;
       }
   } 

   _createDefaultColumns(endUseItems){
       let endUseColumn = {
           title: "End Use",
           field: "id_end_use",
           editor: "list",
           formatter: this._cellFormatter,
           editorParams: {
               values: endUseItems,
               itemFormatter: this._optionFormatter,
               valueToIdConverter: this._valueToIdConverter
           }
       };

       const columns = [
         endUseColumn,
         { title: 2020, field: "2020", editor: true },
         { title: 2025, field: "2025", editor: true },
         { title: 2030, field: "2030", editor: true },
       ];

       return columns;
   }


   _valueToIdConverter(selectableValue){
       //defines what data is returned from the table as
       //replacement for the stored object / displayed label
       return selectableValue.id;
   }

   _cellFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
       //defines how table cells are shown
       let selectableValue = cell.getValue();        
       return selectableValue.toString();        
   }

   _optionFormatter(label, selectableValue, item, element){  
       //defines how options of the cell editor are shown
       return selectableValue.toString();
   } 

   _endUseItems(){       
       let items = []
       let endUseRows = this._context.endUses.rows
       for (let row of endUseRows){
           let id = row[0];
           let label = row[1];
           let description = row[2];
           let value = new SelectableValue(id, label, description)
           let item = {
               'value': value, //Value stored in table; includes unique id
               'label': label  //Used as label for the currently selected item
                               //when cell editor is openend
           }
           items.push(item);
       }
       return items;
   }

   _convertValues(displayData, columns){
       let data = structuredClone(displayData);
       for (let column of columns){
           let _valueToIdConverter = this._valueToIdConverter(column);
           if(_valueToIdConverter){
               let field = column.field;
               for(let row of data){
                   let value = row[field];
                   let id = _valueToIdConverter(value);
                   row[field] = id;
               }
           }
       }
       return data;
   }
  ```